# Wrapping elements with Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, woocommerce

On woocommerce I wanted to have both shipping weight/size and product weight/size visible to the frontend on the customer side. To do that I made extra custom text fields to display the product weight/size but it would only show up under my short description box. I wanted it to display in my more info tabs on the product page and have it dynamically change when the user clicks each different item variation. I've figured out how to do all that but now I just need to format it into a table to match my other tabs.

Here's the current code:

```
<table class="shop_attributes">
    <div class="d-field" data-field-id="product_size">
            <strong class="d-field__label d-field__label--above">product_size</strong>
            <div class="d-field__content">
                <p>66 x 81 x 61</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="d-field" data-field-id="product_weight">
            <strong class="d-field__label d-field__label--above">product_weight</strong>
            <div class="d-field__content">
                <p>128</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</table>
```

And I want to turn it into this in order for the table to properly display like my other ones:

```
<table class="shop_attributes">
    <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--weight">
    <div class="d-field" data-field-id="product_size">
        <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">
            <strong class="d-field__label d-field__label--above">product_size</strong>
        </th>
        <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">
            <div class="d-field__content">
                <p>66 x 81 x 61</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--weight">
    <div class="d-field" data-field-id="product_weight">
        <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">
            <strong class="d-field__label d-field__label--above">product_weight</strong>
        </th>
        <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">
            <div class="d-field__content">
                <p>128</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I use jquery to wrap all the right elements in the right order to get to that result?

Comment: Both your *current* and *desired* HTML markup are wrong. `<div>` is not a valid child of `<table>`. So, either change the tag or reconsider your problem. Also `<th>` is no a valid child of `<div>` etc etc.

Comment: The div was written by a plugin I am using and I'm unable to change/remove it without breaking it.

Comment: Sorry to say, but you should fix the plugin first.